# jsPDF justify text

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to apply some changes on [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library to be able to justify text.

I'm having trouble to find the right value for **Tw** (word spacing).

In [jspdf.js](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/513573698f8c2e5bef6eb17ad54813ca564fc71e/jspdf.js#L1413) (L:1413) I have added this code:

```
if (align) {
    ...                
    else if (align === 'justify') {
       left = x;
    }
    else {
        throw new Error('Unrecognized alignment option, use "center" or "right".');
    }
    prevX = x;
    text = '(' + da[0];

    let pdfPageWidth = this.internal.pageSize.width;
    let wordSpacing;
    if( align === 'justify' ) {
        let fontSize = this.internal.getFontSize();
        let nWords = da[0].trim().split(/\s+/).length;
        let textWidth = this.getStringUnitWidth(da[0].replace(/\s+/g, '')) / this.internal.scaleFactor;
        wordSpacing = (Math.max(0, (pdfPageWidth - textWidth) / Math.max(1, nWords - 1));
        wordSpacing += ' Tw\n';
        text = wordSpacing + text;
    }
    ...
}
```

The idea was to extract the space width by doing (pageWidth - textWidth) / numberOfWords -1. I can't get the correct word space.

**Output example**

```
BT
/F1 16 Tf
18.4 TL
0 g
28.35 756.85 Td
19.00357142857142 Tw
(And a little bit it adélkfjalké.) Tj
ET
```

Is there an encoding problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which font encoding is used? According to the specification *"Word spacing shall be applied to every occurrence of the single-byte character code 32 in a string when using a simple font or a composite font that defines code 32 as a single-byte code. It shall not apply to occurrences of the byte value 32 in multiple-byte codes."* If you have an encoding which does not encode the space glyph as a single byte 0x20, word spacing won't be applied as desired.

Comment: I have found this comment also on the pdfkit library. I'm using utf-8 but I have no clue how to make it code 32.

Comment: UTF-8 is not a proper PDF font encoding. You should check the encoding of the current PDF font. If it is e.g. a pure two-byte encoding (e.g. Identity-H), you cannot use word spacing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about PDF, this is what is specified in jsPDF: "Because of Adobe's focus on "you subset your fonts!" you are not supposed to have a font that maps directly Unicode (UCS2 / UTF16BE) code to font GID, but you could fudge it with "Identity-H" encoding and custom CIDtoGID map that mimics Unicode code page. There, however, all characters in the stream are treated as GIDs, including BOM, which is the reason we need to skip BOM in content text (i.e. that that is tied to a font)."

Comment: Identity-H is a pure 16-bit encoding. Thus, word spacing is not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries I have found the working code solution :D. It works also with array of text as param.

```
        } else if (align === 'justify') {
          left = x;
        }
        else {
          throw new Error(
            'Unrecognized alignment option, use "center" or "right".'
          );
        }
        prevX = x;
        text = '(' + da[0];

        var pdfPageWidth = this.internal.pageSize.width;
        var wordSpacing;
        var fontSize = this.internal.getFontSize();
        if( align === 'justify' ) {
          var nWords = da[0].trim().split(/\s+/).length;
          var textWidth = this.getStringUnitWidth(da[0]) * fontSize / k;

          wordSpacing = (Math.max(0, ((pdfPageWidth - x - marginRight) - textWidth) / Math.max(1, nWords - 1))) * k;
          // Do not justify if wordSpacing is too high
          wordSpacing = ( wordSpacing > 50 ? 0 : wordSpacing ) + ' Tw\n';

          text = wordSpacing + text;
        }

        for (var i = 1, len = da.length; i < len; i++) {
          var delta = maxLineLength - lineWidths[i];
          if (align === "center") delta /= 2;
          if (align === "justify") { // TODO: improve code duplication
            delta = 0;
            var nWords = da[i].trim().split(/\s+/).length;
            var textWidth = this.getStringUnitWidth(da[i]) * fontSize / k;

            wordSpacing = (Math.max(0, ((pdfPageWidth - x - marginRight) - textWidth) / Math.max(1, nWords - 1))) * k;
            // Do not justify if wordSpacing is too high
            wordSpacing = ( wordSpacing > 50 ? 0 : wordSpacing ) + ' Tw\n';
            text += ") Tj\n" + ((left - prevX) + delta) + " -" + leading + " Td\n" + wordSpacing + "(" + da[i];
          } else {
            // T* = x-offset leading Td ( text )
            text += ") Tj\n" + ((left - prevX) + delta) + " -" + leading + " Td (" + da[i];
          }
          prevX = left + delta;
        }
      } else {
        text = ' 0 Tw\n (' + da.join(") Tj\nT* (");
      }
```

Here is my [PR](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/1469)

Answer (score 9):

I answered you on github
I wrote my own justification code into my refactored jsPDF according to your suggestion.

Check it out...

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1016#issuecomment-329957940

Edited:

Oh wait, I can probably help with a direct answer. I think you just have to change it like this:

```
var wordSpacing = (Math.max(0, (pdfPageWidth - textWidth) / Math.max(1, nWords - 1)) * this.internal.scaleFactor);

if (align) {
    ...                
    else if (align === 'justify') {
        var wordSpacingPerLine = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = da.length; i < len; i++) {
            wordSpacingPerLine.push(((this.internal.pageSize.width - lineWidths[i]) / (da[i].split(" ").length - 1) * k).toFixed(2));
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Error('Unrecognized alignment option, use "center" or "right".');
    }
    prevX = x;
    text = '(' + da[0];

    let pdfPageWidth = this.internal.pageSize.width;
    let wordSpacing;
    if( align === 'justify' ) {
        text =  wordSpacingPerLine[0]  + ' Tw\n' + text;
    }
    ...
}
```

You have to do add the specific WordSpacing for every line except the last line. Last line is then left aligned.

Here an example:

```
BT
/F1 16 Tf
18.4 TL
0 g
4.869500000212597 Tw
28.35 813.54 Td
(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur abore et dolore) Tj
3.5284444446334158 Tw
0.00 -18.40 Td
(magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et) Tj
2.0876000001700574 Tw
0.00 -18.40 Td
(accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd) Tj
1.329500000212585 Tw
0.00 -18.40 Td
(gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor) Tj
1.329500000212585 Tw
0.00 -18.40 Td
(sit amet.) Tj
ET
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and include it here. Linking to external websites is highly discouraged in SO.

Comment: Cant because it is a refactored branch of the git repo.

But the solution is to add the scaleFactor to the wordSpace-Value.

Comment: Great! Not sure how correct is the answer but +1 for the effort!

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to do, I must be missing something. (Math.max(0, (pdfPageWidth - textWidth) / Math.max(1, nWords - 1)) / this.getStringUnitWidth(' ') * fontSize / this.internal.scaleFactor);

Comment: But why do you calculate this.getStringUnitWidth of Space multiplied with fontSize? This doesnt make any sense. WordSpace is the width of the Space. So: 
1. you calculate the width of each word of the line and sum it up. 
2. substract the sum from the width of the line. This is your wordspace you have for all words in this line. 
3. Now you divide it the width you have left for spaces by the number of words -1. 
4. now you multiply it with the scaleFactor
5. set the result as wordSpace for that specific line

Comment: Check the result on github:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1016#issuecomment-329960894

Comment: I did update the code example. Maybe my error is on getStringUnitWdith, do I need to pass the fontSize and style to the function? And why do you multiply by scaleFactor the wordSpacing, shouldn't be everything in scale already? Isn't Tw a coefficient? I would use your fork but there are too many changes on the code base. Thanks

Comment: sry, you are right, you have to multiply with the fontSize if you use the original getStringUnitWidth. But you should not calculate again the textWidth by using removing the spaces, because you mess up with the widths...

Comment: I changed the code and i assume, that you do not use multiple lines in one text-call

Comment: Could you please update your code in the answer and show how you calculate the textWidth and pageWidth?

Comment: pageWidth is what you get by this.internal.pageSize.height * scaleFactor.
textWidth is what you get by getStringUnitWidth.

Answer (score 0):

When using a custom font (ttf etc) Justify text can be done with a javascript to place all words on the correct position. See [stackoverflow justify text with custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515025/jspdf-justify-text-with-custom-font/58252425#58252425)